# Is it possibly to call defined? on a dynamic instance variable name?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to call check `defined?` on a dynamic instance variable name?  What I want is to be able to do something like this:

```
dynamic_attr = 'foo'
define_method :my_method do
  if defined? instance_variable_get("@#{dynamic_attr}") # Obviously fails, but you see what I'm getting at...
    ....
  end
end
```

Of course this fails because `defined?` is a special form that is looking at literals and thus returns `"method"` in this case because it's looking at the actual `instance_variable_get` method.  And of course `instance_variable_get("@foo")` is going to return `nil` if I ever called `@foo = nil` so it's indistinguishable from having never been set.  Is there any way I can see if `@foo` was defined with the same semantics as `defined?` but in a dynamic way?

Comment: You can't use `"@#{dynamic_attr}"` because that actually returns `"@foo"`, which is not the variable's name, that's its content. Nor can you use `@dynamic_attr` because that's not the name of the variable, `dynamic_attr` is. Try assigning to `@dynamic_attr` and use that name when you try to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange that nobody mentioned that. There is also [`Object#instance_variable_defined?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_defined%3F).

```
dynamic_attr = 'foo'
define_method :my_method do
  if instance_variable_defined?("@#{dynamic_attr}") 
    ....
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah!  That's even better, sorry David but gotta give this one the check.

Answer (score 2):

If I did get your question, you'd need to check whether an instance variable is defined. `Object#instance_variable_get` retrieves a *value* of an existing variable or `nil` if not exists, not the instance variable name.

You can check the definition of dynamically created variable name by its membership to all existing like:

```
dynamic_attr = 'foo'
define_method :my_method do
  if instance_variables.member? "@#{dynamic_attr}".to_sym
    ....
  end
end
```

See array returned with `Object#instance_variables` contains symbols so you need to convert an argument with `String#to_sym` to compare apples with apples.